# How can delivered array in event function on javascript with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, rendering, react-props

There is two screen. First picture is show list. If clicked Button which is next to search Button, second picture is showed. Second is select filter. When user select options in filter and clicked "적용" Button, list will be changed.

[image][image]

And there code is here.

```
    ...
const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
const [postsPerPage] = useState(6);
const [area] = useState(location.state.area)
const [city] = useState(location.state.city)

// all list
const locList = restList.filter(
    key => (key.address.includes(area) && key.address.includes(city))
);

//about Modal
const openModal = () => {
    setModalOpen(true);
}
const closeModal = () => {
    setModalOpen(false);
}

...
let target;
let foodList = [[], []]
const sel_Food = (e) => {
    if (e.target.tagName === "BUTTON") {
        target = e.target.innerText;
        if (!foodList.includes(target)) 
            foodList[0].push(target)
    } else {
        target = e.target.parentNode.nextSibling.innerText;
        foodList[1] = target
    }
}

//make list
const list = (foodList) => {
    let result = [];
    if (foodList[0].length === 1) {
        result = locList.filter(key => key.foodType.includes(foodList[0][0]))
    } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < foodList[0].length; i++) {
            let tmp = locList.filter(key => key.foodType.includes(foodList[0][i]))
            result.push(...tmp)
        }
    }
    if (foodList[1].length != 0) {
        result = result.filter(key => key.friendly.includes(foodList[1]))
    }
    return result
}
return (
    <div>
        ... {
            (locList.length === 0)
                ? ...
                : <div>
                        <div className="btn_class_list">
                            ...
                            <React.Fragment>
                                <button className="button_filter" onClick={openModal}><img className="icon_filter" src={icon_filter} alt="icon_filter"/></button>
                                <Modal_Restaurant open={modalOpen} close={closeModal} header="필터">
                                    <p className="langoption">음식 종류</p>
                                    <div>
                                        ...
                                    </div>

                                    <p className="langoption">Halal Standard</p>
                                    <div className="foodtype">
                                        ...
                                    </div>

                                </Modal_Restaurant>
                            </React.Fragment>
                        </div>
                        
                        <Item rlist={currentPosts(locList)} moveTo="restaurant" area={area} city={city}></Item>    //make List
                        <Pagination start={numOfFirst} last={numOfLast} paginate={setCurrentPage}></Pagination>
                    </div>
        }
    </div>
)
```

sel_Food function record option that user selected.
list function make sub list for delivered to Item component.
But I don't know how to delivered array result in list function with "적용" button.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from the question, you need to change the list of items you display according to the filters the user applies. It can be done with the state. As a start, you can try to update the list of items through a filter function and use the state variable to render the filtered results. You'd asked about returning a value when a button is clicked. Buttons have an onClick handler in React. You can pass it a function like this:

```
<Button onClick={handleClick} />
```

or if your function takes any arguments:

```
<Button onClick={() => handlClick(args)} />
```